# Repulsive fixed point and sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across the following exercise :

> Let $f \, : \, \mathbb{R} \, \rightarrow \, \mathbb{R}$ of class $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $a$ be a fixed point of $f$ such that $\vert f'(a) \vert > 1$. Let $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the sequence defined by : $u_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, u_{n+1} = f(u_{n})$. We assume that the sequence $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not stationary. Prove that the sequence $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent.

By contradiction, one can assume that the sequence $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges (to some $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$). By continuity of $f$, it is clear that $\ell$ must be a fixed point of $f$. However, $f$ might have several fixed points and $\ell$ is not necessarily equal to $a$, is it ? If I'm not mistaken, the statement

> Prove that $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent.

should be replaced with :

> Prove that $(u_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent to $a$.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. A priori it could converge to another fixed point where the derivative is in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Yes, like for $f(x) = x^2$.